# Rewrite single page url in Wordpress with .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a page in Wordpress that is a child of a parent page. Its url comes up thusly:

```
www.domain.com/parent/subpage/
```

There are about five other subpages of the parent. However, for the one specific subpage, I want to change the URL to show up under root, like this:

```
www.domain.com/subpage/
```

Is there any way of doing this with `.htaccess`, or with a plugin? I can't figure out how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect this single page with just

```
Redirect /parent/subpage/ http://www.domain.com/subpage/
```

See [Redirect Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) for more information.